# Unable to perform simple Excel.Application event handling

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto

I am new to Events Handling on a VSTO.
I did som extensive reserch online, including digging the Microsoft documentation and trying to apply a [practical but old example](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/822750/how-to-handle-events-for-excel-by-using-visual-basic-net) from the support center.

The problem with this example is that it does not work on the `Excel.Application` instance which calls `ThisAddin`. So I tried one of my own:

- I have an Excel 2010 application wide VSTO, created through VS 2017.
- I added a new file `MyEvents.vb`, which contains the following:

.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Module MyEvents

    WithEvents ThisApp As Excel.Application '= Globals.ThisAddIn.Application

    Private Sub ThisApp_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(Sh As Object, Target As Range, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles ThisApp.SheetBeforeDoubleClick
        Dim FromSheet As Excel.Worksheet = Sh
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Event triggered: ThisApp_SheetBeforeDoubleClick in {0} or {1}", FromSheet, Target.Worksheet.Name)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisApp_WorkbookActivate(Wb As Workbook) Handles ThisApp.WorkbookActivate
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Event triggered: ThisApp_WorkbookActivate")
    End Sub

End Module
```

When I compile, open a new workbook and try double clicking or activating another workbook: nothing happens. I must be missing something obvious.. I feel I lack some fundamentals on events handling via VSTO, and I would be glad to be proposed some extra reading on the matter.

For example:

- Do I need `WithEvents ThisApp As Excel.Application =
  Globals.ThisAddIn.Application` or just `WithEvents ThisApp As
  Excel.Application`? i.e. can I bind the event to a given object (Application, Worksheet, etc) or do I need to check the caller in my `Sub` once the event has been triggered, and why?
- Is it possible to handle VSTO events from a class, or does it have to be a Module? Can it be in a `Module` in a `Namespace`? Does/can it be linked to a `Shared WithEvents ThisApp`?
- What happens if it is not a `Shared Class`? Will it run my handling `Sub` as many time as I currently have instances of that `Class`?

As one can see, I am a little lost here.. I wanted to run all these tests by myself but I am not event able to do something which should be pretty basic.. !

Comment: The general VB.NET documentation is not applicable for this situation. It's pretty simple for VB.NET, see the VSTO documentation on the topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-create-event-handlers-in-office-projects?view=vs-2017

Comment: Thanks Cindy, and whilst your article was useful, it made me realise my code was actually 99.99% correct! So `WithEvents ThisApp As Excel.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application` is great, but it needs to be initialized and that will not happen until a sub or function from within this same `Module` is called. All was needed was to add a `Public Sub StartEvents():End Sub` (yes EMPTY) inside the `Module`. Then events are triggered once this `StartEvents` sub is called, for example from within the `Sub ThisAddIn_Startup()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whoever might be interested:

## MyEvents.vb

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Module MyEvents

    WithEvents ThisApp As Excel.Application

    'Start listening to Events thrown by ExcelApp
    Sub StartEvents(ExcelApp as Excel.Application)
        ThisApp = ExcelApp 
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisApp_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(Sh As Object, Target As Range, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles ThisApp.SheetBeforeDoubleClick
        Dim FromSheet As Excel.Worksheet = Sh
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Event triggered: ThisApp_SheetBeforeDoubleClick in {0} or {1}", FromSheet, Target.Worksheet.Name)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisApp_WorkbookActivate(Wb As Workbook) Handles ThisApp.WorkbookActivate
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Event triggered: ThisApp_WorkbookActivate")
    End Sub

End Module
```

## ThisAddIn.vb

```
Public Class ThisAddIn

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        MyEvents.StartEvents(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application)
    End Sub

End Class
```